# Finding the repeating part of a signal

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory

How do people "synchronize" to a periodic signal? In other words, given an oscillating auditory signal, how do people decide where the beat is? Assuming a "beat" divides a signal into equal repeating parts. Do they converge after a certain amount of time or is it a sudden decision? Alternatively, if there is a name for this type of beat-seeking experiment, this would also be appreciated.

Comment: Related https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/11041/11318 possibly the Kelso paper may have some interesting insights.

Comment: @AliceD it's not specifically addressing binaural beats and I've clarified what I mean by synchronize.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean with 'beat'. Periodic signals do not have to contain any beats? A sinusoid doesn't have beats, yet is periodic. Looped [white] noise is periodic, yet doesn't contain beats.

Comment: [Kaernbach (1992)](http://asa.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1121/1.403948) looked at how people perceived repeated samples of white noise. Is that the type of thing you are looking for?

Comment: @AliceD clarified my definition of "beat"

Comment: @StrongBad yep, precisely